# Словосочетание "опаздывание на уроки". Правильно ли оно согласовано?

Tags: согласование, управление, словосочетания

Как правильно: "опаздывани**е** на урок**и**" или "опаздывани**я** на урок**и**"? И есть ли разница между словами "опаздывание" и "опоздание"?
Не могу понять... По правилам согласования, если **опаздывание**, то **на урок**, а если **опаздывания**, то **на уроки**. Верно?

Или это управление, а не согласование? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как правильно: "Опаздывание на уроки" или "Опаздывания на уроки"?

Обычно используется единственное число: **опаздывание**. Но **опаздывания** тоже допустимо, например:
*В этом учебном году ухудшилась статистика опаздываний на уроки и прогулов.* (Во множественном числе употребляется редко, в основном в стиле канцелярита, я думаю.)

> И есть ли разница между словами "опаздывание" и "опоздание"?

Да, есть разница, хотя её не так просто уловить и понять. Я приведу цитату из работы А.Исаченко "Грамматический строй русского языка..."

Существительное **опоздание** обозначает название опредмеченного явления (nomen rei), в то время как существительное **опаздывание** обозначает отвлечённое действие (nomen actionis).

> По правилам согласования, если опаздывание, то на урок, а если
>   опаздывания, то на уроки. Верно?

Здесь нет такой связи. Можно сказать "опаздывание на уроки" — здесь нет ошибки.

> Или это управление, а не согласование?

Да, это управление.

**Дополнение**. Цитаты с использованием слова "опаздывание" во множественном числе.

> Войдя в гостиную, Степан Аркадьич извинился, объяснил, что был
>   задержан тем князем, который был всегдашним козлом-искупителем всех
>   его **опаздываний** и отлучек... ("Анна Каренина", Л.Н. Толстой)
>
> Стоило поставить у каждой буровой по культ-будке — и как не бывало
>   **опаздываний** на работу. (Максим Горький)
>
> ...Путеводитель с точно установленным расписанием (без **опаздываний**)
>   (Евгений Замятин)
>
> Тогда не будет **опаздываний**, проволочек времени (журнал "Театр", 1960)
>
> Если не считать крошечных, извинительных, **опаздываний**... (В.И.
>   Немирович-Данченко, 1979)

Answer (score 1):

Изложу мое понимание вопроса. По-моему, *опаздывание*, образованное от глагола несов. вида *опаздывать*, уместно употреблять, когда подразумевается явление или когда действие еще не завершено.

Явление:

> В этом случае так называемые последователи и ученики обречены на трагикомические скачки с препятствиями, на **постоянное и безнадежное опаздывание**. [С. Л. Цимбал. Мейерхольдовские эпигоны (1938.01.26) // «Советское искусство» Орган Всесоюзного комитета по делам Искусств при Совнаркоме Союза ССР № 10 (416), 1938]

Действие еще не завершено:

> Подъем вверх ― это нарастающее **опаздывание**: все больше видно вокруг, все больше мест называется, все больше оснований для письма, все более неясен будущий текст, абсолютный топоним, ибо он весь здесь, в настоящем; тотальный топоним ― Лолита. [Дмитрий Замятин. Экономическая география «Лолиты» // «Октябрь», 2003]

*Опаздывание* — слово малоупотребимое, "режет глаз и ухо" (см. ответ Niemand), поэтому я бы советовал использовать вместо него синоним "опоздание" везде, где это возможно.

Одно дело, если нас интересует *опаздывание* на уроки как явление (но только в ед.ч.), другое — если мы говорим о случаях *опоздания* на уроки (действие завершено).

Если речь идет о явлении, можно употребить как *опаздывание*, так и *опоздание* (ср.: решение/решание задач). Но если речь идет о конкретных случаях опоздания, то, по-моему, гораздо лучше писать "опоздание на урок" и "опоздания на уроки" (завершенные действия), а не *опаздывание*, *опаздывания* (незавершенные действия).

Статистики учитывают *опоздания*, а не *опаздывания* (я вчера опаздывал, но пришел вовремя). Поисковик не находит "статистики опаздываний", но приносит больше тысячи по запросу "статистики опазданий".

Comment: Я добавил цитат в свой ответ. Всё никак не привыкну, что мне здесь не доверяют в вопросах поиска цитат :) Как обычно, старался выбирать цитаты известных людей и/или из добротных изданий.

Comment: @grizzly Не вижу, где я выражал Вам недоверие (уж точно, не намеревался его выражать). Я не отрицаю возможности употребления слова *опаздывание*, но хочу показать его малоупотребимость (или ошибочность, в примере со  "статистикой опаздываний")

Comment: *(но только в ед.ч.)* — Я подумал, Вы настаиваете, что "опаздывание" не бывает во множественном числе. Поэтому решил привести побольше таких примеров.

Comment: @grizzly, Я думаю так. Как явление, *опаздывание* должно употребляться в ед.ч.. Но как сутация оно может повторяться, а значит оправдано  упорт. мн. ч.  (я опаздывал несколько раз,  это были опаздывания, однако не все мои опаздывания закончились опозданием) .

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.

Answer (score 0):

> > И есть ли разница между словами "опаздывание" и "опоздание"?

"Опаздывание", хотя и есть в словарях, употребляется настолько редко, что режет глаз и ухо. Куда лучше "опоздание" с тем же значением. "Опоздания на уроки" - на мой взгляд, только так. "Многократные и однократные" тут ни при чем.

Почему есть в словарях? На мой взгляд, по формальной причине: раз есть слово "опаздывать", то должно быть и "опаздывание" - отглагольное существительное. Вот и включили.

P.S. Между прочим, похожее слово "запаздывание" - вполне обычное, употребляется нередко. Такой вот парадокс.

Comment: Спасибо за критику. Действительно, я неправильно предположил различие. Я откорректировал свой ответ. Что думаете по поводу остальных вопросов?

Comment: *В этом учебном году ухудшилась статистика опаздываний на уроки и прогулов.* - неужели это не придуманная фраза?!

Comment: Нет. Подкорректировал какую-то цитату близко к тексту (там было подобное про лекции, а не уроки).

Comment: Вообще-то я даже сначала засомневался, есть ли такое слово - опаздывание. *...в то время как существительное опаздывание обозначает отвлечённое действие* -- вот с этим *отвлеченным* весьма непросто придумать *конкретный* пример. Опаздывание на уроки не годится - это "опредмеченное явление".

Comment: Я согласен с Вами, что слово редко используется. Поиск находит в основном довольно старые источники — похоже, оно ускоренными темпами выходит из употребления. Но не зная мотивации автора вопроса (который, видимо, не носитель языка), я не стал обсуждать это.

Comment: В школе на листовке я увидел словосочетание "опаздывание на уроки" как одно из условий какого-то мероприятия или конкурса, уже не помню. Кто-то рядом со мной отметил что словосочетание составлено грамматически неправильно, и правильно писать: опаздываниЯ на уроки. Я - носитель языка, но довольно безграмотный ;)  Поэтому я начал искать информацию в интернете.